# How to create a test that checks whether the record already exists in the database

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, xunit, nsubstitute

I am using xUnit to create unit tests for a method that needs to query a database to verify that the record already exists. In my tests I'm using NSubstitute to `Mock` my repository.

Thus:

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    public MyTestClass()
    { 
        myRepository = Substitute.For<IMyRepository>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void My_Test()
    {
        var myService = new MyService(myRepository);

        var result = myService.Create(mockObject);

        ....
    }
```

This is the implementation of my referenced service:

```
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(IMyRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository
    }

    IMyRepository _repository;

    public X Create(MyObject mockObject)
    {
        var result =  _repository.CheckIfExists(mockObject.Name); //This return an NAME for example;

        if (result == mockObject.Name)
        {
            return X.Error("Message...")
        }
    }
}
```

The question is:

How do I test the `if (result == mockObject.Name)` of my service, since my repository is FAKE? I need this message `return X.Error("Message...")` on Test class.

How can I test this snippet of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mock/substitute would need to be configured to behave as expected for the test

For example

```
public class MyTestClass {
    public MyTestClass()  
        myRepository = Substitute.For<IMyRepository>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void My_Test() {
        //Arrange
        myRepository.CheckIfExists(mockObject.Name).Returns(mockObject.Name);

        var myService = new MyService(myRepository);

        //Act
        var result = myService.Create(mockObject);

        //Assert
        //....check that the returned result is as expected.
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! :) Thanks!